# How to Modify view Model returned from base Controller (MVC4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to implement a base controller, app services, repository design. I am new to this level of OO design but have gotten it pretty much complete. The remaining hurdle is how to handle extending my base controller.

My Goals:

1. have a base controller that can stand on its own...i.e. you could have a specific controller inherit from it but itself be empty and have it work.
2. In cases where I need to extend the base controller, have the
   ability to do so in the specific controller.

Here is what I have:

Base Controller:

```
public class BaseControllerSingle<TRepository, TViewModelSingle> : BaseController
...
// GET: /InventoryMgmt/ManageItems/Edit/5
        public virtual ActionResult Edit( 
            int id = 0,
            string pageTitleNoun = "",
            Expression<Func<TRepository, bool>> predicate = null
        )
        {
            TViewModelSingle viewModelSingle = new TViewModelSingle();

            ViewBag.Mode = "EDIT";

            if (id == 0) //Add new company mode
            {
                viewModelSingle = _baseAppServSingle.CreateNewViewModel(CurrentUserId);
                ViewBag.Header = "Create New " + pageTitleNoun;
                ViewBag.Mode = "NEW";
                return View(viewModelSingle);
            }

            //else edit existing record mode
            viewModelSingle = _baseAppServSingle.CreateEditViewModel(id, predicate);
            ViewBag.Header = "Edit " + pageTitleNoun;

            return View(viewModelSingle);
        }
```

And my specific controller. Note the code in this is incorrect (specifically"ItemViewModel viewModel = actionResult(ItemViewModel);"...but trying to show what I am attempting, which is essentially to extract the view model from the action result, manipulate it further, then return it.

```
public class ManageItemsController : BaseController
...
// GET: /InventoryMgmt/ManageItems/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            ActionResult actionResult = GetBaseControllerSingle().Edit(
                "Material", 
                id, 
                x => x.Id == id && x.CompanyId == CurrentCompanyId);

            ItemViewModel viewModel = actionResult(ItemViewModel);
            if (id == 0)
            {
                viewModel = _manageItemsAppServ.CreateNewViewModel(viewModel, CurrentCompanyId);
            }

            viewModel.DDLOptions = _manageItemsAppServ.CreateFilterOptionsViewModel(CurrentCompanyId);
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

Comment: Hm... seems like you are getting into the weeds.  I'd recommend refactoring your code so that you can more easily reuse it instead of trying to get an elaborate routing scheme to do it for you.  Have you tried using partial views to accomplish your goal?  Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I have decided to re-write some of the code to remove this necessity. I think maybe it could be done with Ninject...but that's not something I wanted to get into right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to re-write some of the code to remove this necessity. I think maybe it could be done with Ninject...but that's not something I wanted to get into right now